# How to render JSON attributes conditionally in React - Render if the attribute exists

Tags: reactjs

I am reading a JSON file in react. In some records the attribute `Attachments` exists which is basically an array and in some records it doesn't. I am trying to apply an conditional render where it will check if the attribute exists in the record, then it will render it's elements otherwise it will skip the record. It is giving me an error of "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')". My code is below:

```
 {data.map((record) => (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{record.UniqueName}</td>
                            <td>{record.StatusString}</td>
                            <React.Fragment>
                                if (!record.Attachments) {
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                                {record.Attachments.map((line, index) => (
                                                    <React.Fragment>
                                                        <td>{line.uniqueAttachmentId}</td>
                                                        <td>{line.Filename}</td>
                                                        <td>{line.id}</td>
                                                    </React.Fragment>
                                                ))}
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                }
                            </React.Fragment>
                        </tr>
                     ))}
```

And the JSON sample is here.

```
[
{
    "StatusString": "Received",
    "UniqueName": "PR95291",
    "Attachments": [
        {
            "uniqueAttachmentId": "QUZLeUFPVkQzUEU0T1kyOmJuTXlNREl4THpBM0x6QTBMek13T1RNeE56UTJNUT09",
            "Filename": "Q882106Q892EOa - IAG Bento Boxes - Perth.pdf",
            "id": "bnMyMDIxLzA3LzA0LzMwOTMxNzQ2MQ=="
        }
    ]
},
{
    "CreateDate": "2021-07-05T05:45:34Z",
    "UniqueName": "PR95291",
}
```

]

In the above JSON example, in the second record the "Attachments" attribute is missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct your condition. I'm assuming your error is thrown at `record.Attachments.map(e=>`

```js
 if (record.Attachments) { // If it exists then run below code block
```

You are using `!` means it will negate the condition value, means
you were checking for if `record.attachment` is not present then run the code.

**SOLUTION**

And you cannot use `if` condition within JSX you need to use ternary operator `condition ? true : false` or `&&` binary add operator.

```js
{
  record.Attachments && record.Attachments.map(()=>{
      // code
    })
}
```

PS:
You can directly use `React.Fragment` as `<> </>`

```js
 {data.map((record) => (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{record.UniqueName}</td>
                            <td>{record.StatusString}</td>
                            <>
                                {record.Attachments &&
                                    record.Attachments.map((line, index) => (
                                                    <>
                                                        <td>{line.uniqueAttachmentId}</td>
                                                        <td>{line.Filename}</td>
                                                        <td>{line.id}</td>
                                                    </>
                                                ))}
                            </>
                        </tr>
                     ))}
```

Comment: If you don't use `<> </>` around your condition `{record.Attachments && ....` then also it will work.

Comment: Hi GodWin, Thanks heaps for your response. It really worked and was very helpful. Thanks alot.

Comment: No problem, You can read about [optional chaining `?.`](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-question-mark-dot)

Answer (score 1):

for validation of array you can use { isArray(data) && data.map((record) => {

})

You can use ternary operator (?) for checking if key exists in your json or not
like record.UniqueName ? {record.UniqueName} : ""

Comment: Hi Sachin, Thanks so much for your response. Really appreciated your time and solution. It was really helpful.